# foundation installation and turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, turbolinks

I just installed foundation in a rails 4 app. Foundation overrwites the layout file.

It replaces:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to just:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
```

is there some sort of incompatibility or should I append back the turbolinks tracking directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no incompatibility. I've used Turbolinks with Foundation without any issues on several projects.

At any rate, I wouldn't think Foundation would affect Turbolinks, as it's just an HTML/CSS/jQuery framework. From what I understand, Turbolinks works by preloading data from links on a page so if you click one, the page loads quicker.

Comment: They work fine together, just keep the original `stylesheet_link_tag` that references turbolinks.